# How to authenticate user on lan?

Tags: windows, authentication

I am deploying a website on server(Windows server 2003) developed in ASP.Net using C#. I made a virtual directory on server for that application and set windows authentication mode in IIS and web.config.

There are a lot of users on LAN, a few of them are needed to authenticate for the application. I have windows usernames of those users in my database.

When user browse the application, the application only accepts the username and password that are of the server account(as a popup appears). But i need the username of the user that is locally accessing the application so that i confirm him from database as a valid user.

The application is hosted on a server (Windows Server 2003, with SQL Server 2008). What changes can be made in IIS for this?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try using active directory / LDAP. then you can create a group and assign those users to this group. so you only have to check whether the user belongs to the group.

[ASP.NET / Active Directory - Supporting auto login for domain users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500413/asp-net-active-directory-supporting-auto-login-for-domain-users)

you don't even have to implement a login form using a DB..

an example using MVC and ASP.NET:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

Comment: Unfortunately the number of users can vary, so i put them in DB. But there is no login form. When user browse for default page, system confirms him as a valid user if he is not a valid user then redirected to another page. I just want when a user browse the site, i get his username(widows user name) and check either it exists in DB or not.

Comment: Ok, I guess you're using basic authentication. you get the information from the http response: [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). at the bottom you see an example how to get the username. you have to read the "Authentication" field and encode it.. maybe there is already a function who does that for C#

Comment: maybe this helps http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Development/BasicAuthenticationC.htm

Comment: Thank you for response.I got the point you told. I want to give a little explanation. There was no javascript code on my application. It was working earlier. But when i deleted the virtual directory and made a new directory on the server, it is not working according to the requirement.